# javascript Change background Based on Time

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so I have been working with javascript for a little bit and Im trying to get it so that the website background changes depending on the time, Day and Night. But It seems that when I run the page that it skips over all the coding, goes to the else statement and run's that

Here Is the code:

```
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
    if(5 < currentTime && currentTime < 18){
        if (document.body) {
            document.body.background = 'images/bg-day.png';
        }
    } else {
        if (document.body) {
            document.body.background = 'images/bg-night.png';
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you try to put your code inside the `<head>`

Comment: BTW, you don't need `if (document.body)`

Comment: first of all you don't close the body tag before closing the html tag. if that didn't fix it, replace all the code with just `<script type="text/javascript"> document.body.background = "images/bg-day.png"; </script>` to see if setting the background works. also make sure that the path to the image is correct (relative to your html page). and last but not least, the background property is deprecated, you should use css instead.

Comment: typing in <script type="text/javascript"> document.body.background = "images/bg-day.png"; </script> did work just as I suspected and I have made sure that the path is correct

Comment: You forgot the url() in background property... document.body.background =
"url(images/bg-day.png)";

Comment: @Tom, it's not CSS, so the link to the image is correct

Answer (score 0):

put all the js codes in

```
window.onload=function(){
    YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

to run them

and also,use
    `document.body.setAttribute("style","background-image: url(/images/xxx.png);")`;

instead of

```
document.body.background=xxx;
```

because when you change css style,browser will refresh element immediately.

Comment: still not working, tried changing the time also with no prevail.

Comment: The OP says that it skips to the else every time, so the code is clearly running.

Comment: setAttribute? i would prefer to use document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(...)"

Answer (score 0):

Your exact code works correctly for me. Try doing:
    document.write(currentTime);

To see if getHours(), etc is working as expected.

Also, what happens if you set currentTime manually?

Comment: not sure how to set current time manually, but it is returning with the correct hour time

Comment: By set it manually I mean just do something like:
    currentTime = 6;