# I want to change image on my page with time

Tags: javascript, html

Example, I want to display image1.jpg for first 10 seconds and then the image2.jpg for next 10 seconds

```
<HTML>
  <body>
     <img src="image1.jpg" aftersometime='this.src="image2.jpg"' />
       <!--  -->
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Comment: are you using jquery , or want pure javascript solution ?

Comment: @laaposto Don't edit questions in this manner! though some things are not really required to post in a question but it should not lose OP's code atleast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

HTML:

```
<img id ="image" src="/image1.jpg" />
```

JS:

```
setInterval(function(){
var src=document.getElementById("image").src;
    if(src.indexOf("image1") != -1){
    document.getElementById("image").src="image2.jpg"
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById("image").src="image1.jpg"
    }


},10000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YD6Bg/)

Answer (score 1):

the functions you need are window.setInterval() or window.setTimeout() for the timing and something like document.getElementById().setAttribute("src","newpath");

If you want to do it with a new attribute such as aftersometime="" I would suggest to call it data-aftersometime="" (according to HTML5 standart) and leave out the this.src part and you need an ID:

img-code:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" id="myimage" data-aftersometime="image2.jpg" />
```

Javascript Code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   var imgref = document.getElementById("myimage");
   imgref.setAttribute("src", imgref.getAttribute("data-aftersometime"));
}, 10*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

found this on an old stack overflow question try this out :)

[javascript Change background Based on Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044544/javascript-change-background-based-on-time)

Check it out through the link. the main piece of code is below

```
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
        if(5 < currentTime && currentTime < 18){
            if (document.body) {
                document.body.background = 'images/bg-day.png';
            }
        } else {
            if (document.body) {
                document.body.background = 'images/bg-night.png';
            }
        }
   </script>
```

Comment: sorry didn't realise will grab it now :)

Comment: How would one configure the time?

Comment: @IanBrindley I was thinking youcould do it on page laod perhaps, and however long they have been on the page from theron it would be implimented

Comment: @Kieranmv95 My point is that you've not explained how the code works.

Comment: @IanBrindley  it was a link from another page it is explained on there hence why i added the link, there's no need to totally repeat the response when the link to it is there :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

**Image Code**

```
<img src="image1.jpg" id="changeimg" aftersometime='this.src="image2.jpg"' />
```

**Javascript**

```
setInterval(function(){
      $("#changeimg").attr("src","");
  },10000);
```

You have to build this code with array....

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this quite easily with a javascript function by using something like

YourElementSelector.setAttribute("src","path-to-your-image");

You will just have to create a function that switches the image path based on an interval of your choice.

alternatively you could set the image as a background image and use javascript to change the CSS to point to the new background you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Your img needs an ID

```
  <img id="myimg" src="image1.jpg" />
```

In JavaScript, you can do something similar to:

```
var IMG_URL1 = "image1.jpg"
var IMG_URL2 = "image2.jpg"

setInterval(function() {
    var myimg = document.getElementById('myimg');
    if (myimg.src === IMG_URL1) {
        myimg.src = IMG_URL2;
    } else {
        myimg.src = IMG_URL1;
    }
}, 10000);
```